# Customer Error: imread read blank (None) image for file- Sagemaker AWS

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker, imread

I am following this [tutorial](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/imageclassification_mscoco_multi_label/Image-classification-multilabel-lst.ipynb) with my custom data and my custom S3 buckets where train and validation data are. I am getting the following error:

```
Customer Error: imread read blank (None) image for file: /opt/ml/input/data/train/s3://image-classification/image_classification_model_data/train/img-001.png
```

I have all my training data are in one folder named '`train`' I have set up my `lst` file like this suggested by [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/image-classification.html),

```
22  1   s3://image-classification/image_classification_model_data/train/img-001.png
86  0   s3://image-classification/image_classification_model_data/train/img-002.png
...
```

My other configurations:

```
s3_bucket = 'image-classification'
prefix =  'image_classification_model_data'


s3train = 's3://{}/{}/train/'.format(s3_bucket, prefix)
s3validation = 's3://{}/{}/validation/'.format(s3_bucket, prefix)

s3train_lst = 's3://{}/{}/train_lst/'.format(s3_bucket, prefix)
s3validation_lst = 's3://{}/{}/validation_lst/'.format(s3_bucket, prefix)



train_data = sagemaker.inputs.TrainingInput(s3train, distribution='FullyReplicated', 
                        content_type='application/x-image', s3_data_type='S3Prefix')

validation_data = sagemaker.inputs.TrainingInput(s3validation, distribution='FullyReplicated', 
                             content_type='application/x-image', s3_data_type='S3Prefix')

train_data_lst = sagemaker.inputs.TrainingInput(s3train_lst, distribution='FullyReplicated', 
                        content_type='application/x-image', s3_data_type='S3Prefix')

validation_data_lst = sagemaker.inputs.TrainingInput(s3validation_lst, distribution='FullyReplicated', 
                             content_type='application/x-image', s3_data_type='S3Prefix')


data_channels = {'train': train_data, 'validation': validation_data, 'train_lst': train_data_lst, 
                 'validation_lst': validation_data_lst}
```

I checked the images downloaded and checked physically, I see the image. Now sure what this error gets thrown out as `blank`. Any suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sagemaker copies the input data you specify in `s3train` into the instance in `/opt/ml/input/data/train/` and that's why you have an error, because as you can see from the error message is trying to concatenate the filename in the `lst` file with the path where it expect the image to be. So just put only the filenames in your `lst`and should be fine (remove the s3 path).

Comment: I tried that and I am getting the following error `ClientError: Unable to start training. Data format not valid for multi-label input. Invalid input data format for multi-label training in train channel. Check your lst files for multiple labels`. Any idea why? I have been trying to search, but no luck. Per your answer, documentation is not up to date or wrong some reason I think!

Comment: Looking at the example you are using a wrong format for multi-label classification, you have to specify multiple labels in each line in your lst file. Anyway you'd better mark this answer as correct and open a new specific question, so we can help you better.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry, I didn't get `you have to specify multiple labels in each line in your lst file`. However, I have `22 1 img-001.png` and `86 0 img-002.png` etc.. where class labels of `1`, `0` are there. Isn't that specifying multiple labels in `lst`?

Comment: I mean multiple labels for each image, since you are using multi-label..

Comment: I see, thanks! Mine is just a simple binary classification. In that case, I guess I should keep it as 0.